# Spring security rest plugin for Grails3

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

The latest spring security rest plugin works only with Grails 2.x. Could someone provide the plugin details for Grails 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security Rest and it's docs have been updated.

You need to add the following to `build.gradle`

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    //Other dependencies

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
}
```

Next, you need to run Spring Security quickstart

```
grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp Person Role
```

Finally, you need to configure the filter chain but adding the following into your `application.groovy`.

**application.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/api/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ],

    //Traditional chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
    ]
]
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35062082/715608) goes into more depth.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a compatible Spring Security REST plugin with Grails 3.x yet.