# How to Configure Spring Security Rest for Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, gradle, spring-security

How do you configure [Spring Security Rest Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) for Grails 3.x (currently I'm using Grails 3.1.0 RC2).

<del>The plugin page says to "Add compile `:spring-security-rest:${version}` to your `BuildConfig.groovy`," but `BuildConfig.groovy` has been removed from Grails 3.x</del>

**edit:** the docs on the plugin page have been updated

Answer (score 1):

SO I got this working.  First off, the documentation located [here][1] is much more up to date.  You need to add the following to `build.gradle`

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    //Other dependencies

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
}
```

Next, you need to run Spring Security quickstart

```
grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp Person Role
```

Finally, you need to configure the filter chain but adding the following into your `application.groovy`.

**application.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/api/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ],

    //Traditional chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
    ]
]
```

**Alternatives:**
I decided to move the configuration to `application.yml`, so I'm not using two different configuration syntaxes.

**Alternative config #1:** 
*using* `application.yml` *with standard default settings*

```
grails:

    # other config values

    plugin.springsecurity:
        userLookup.userDomainClassName: 'com.company.product.Person'
        userLookup.authorityJoinClassName: 'com.company.product.PersonRole'
        authority.className: 'com.company.product.Role'
        controllerAnnotations.staticRules:    
            - {pattern: '/', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/error', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/index', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/index.gsp', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/shutdown', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/assets/**', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/**/js/**', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/**/css/**', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/**/images/**', access: ['permitAll']}
            - {pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']}
        filterChain.chainMap:
            - {pattern: '/assets/**', filters: 'none'}
            - {pattern: '/**/js/**', filters: 'none'}
            - {pattern: '/**/css/**', filters: 'none'}
            - {pattern: '/**/images/**', filters: 'none'}
            - {pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'}
              #Stateless chain
            - {pattern: '/api/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'}
                  #Traditional chain
                - {pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'}
```

I also *(this is totally optional)*

- removed all of the generated config that pertains to serving GSPs since my app is just an API
- configured the plugin to persist the authorization token using GORM
- replaced the default bearer tokens config with the X-Auth-Token config

so I ended up with this

**Alternative config #2:** 
*using* `application.yml` *with API only (No GSPs) with GORM token storage and X-Auth-Tokens instead of Bearer Tokens*

```
grails:

    # other config values

    plugin.springsecurity:
        userLookup.userDomainClassName: 'com.company.product.Person'
        userLookup.authorityJoinClassName: 'com.company.product.PersonRole'
        authority.className: 'com.company.product.Role'
        filterChain.chainMap:
            #Stateless chain
            - {pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'}
        rest.token:
                storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName: 'com.company.product.AuthenticationToken'
                validation:
                    useBearerToken: false
                    headerName: 'X-Auth-Token'
```

Comment: I don't know where did you get that from. The documentation at http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html#configuration mentions `build.gradle`. If you found a place that mentions `BuildConfig.groovy` please let me know to fix it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal it's in the last line on this page: https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroSánchez-Mariscal, and thanks for an awesome plugin.